# Flutter list scroll animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

#### Question

I was searching on dribble for some animation when I saw this post:
[post](https://dribbble.com/shots/8065688-Online-shop-Animation)

In the concept, there is a list of an element with a custom scroll effect. It's possible to replicate that effect with flutter?
Can this be achieved with some sort of custom physics? Looking through the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics-class.html) I wasn't able to understand if ScrollPhysics can help me with that

Thanks